# *unusual* approach to memory saving?

Tags: c++, file-storage

I was reading in a textbook on c++ about IOstreams, and I came across this:

> Whenever you want to store information
>   on the computer for longer than the
>   running time of a program, the usual
>   approach is to collect the data into a
>   logically cohesive whole and store it
>   on a permanent storage medium as a
>   file.
>   (Quoted from Programming Abstractions in C++)

Is there an UNUSUAL approach to storing data?

Comment: This question isn't really possible to answer definitively?

Comment: Of course there is. Rather it should have been phrased "the logical approach" which, in general, means the only and/or best approach.

Comment: Too many big words here: "cohesive", "permanent storage medium", come on, even my grandmother knows that you can save stuff in files.

Comment: The problem with this question is it has a number of possibly correct extremely general answers. This is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Alexandre: Writing it so simply wouldn't be an "abstraction."

Comment: "real men just upload their important stuff on ftp, and let the rest of the world mirror it" - Linus T.

Comment: Storing the data into Non-volatile memory, such as Flash or Battery-backed RAM, is an UNUSUAL method for desktop platforms, but not for embedded systems.

Comment: Storing into a named shared segment, storing it into a named pipe

Answer (score 2):

Pushing across to a server, operating systems (experimental) that let you freeze parts of RAM etc.

This is a very vague question, and really, has no good answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the info :) Yes, I agree, this is more of a discussion than a question, though, it didn't seem to fit in with the "Programmers" stack overflow site.

Answer (score 1):

i guess if you store it at some place in the RAM, and hope for it to be there when you run your program again, that would be an unusual way of storing :-)